# Attribute error: function object has no attribute in python

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, attributes

This is my code to call a function 10 times and measure the time

```
    import threading
    import logging, logging.handlers
    import hpclib
    import json
    import time
    from datetime import datetime
    from features import *


    class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, target, *args):
            self._target = target
            self._args = args
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
            self._target(*self._args)

    def datapaths(ipaddress, testlogfile):
        #initialize logging system
        testlogger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
        testlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file = open(testlogfile,'w')
        file.close()
        # This handler writes everything to a file.
        h1 = logging.FileHandler(testlogfile)
        f = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")
        h1.setFormatter(f)
        h1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        testlogger.addHandler(h1)
        mylib = hpclib.hpclib(ipaddress)
        for i in range(10):
            t1=datetime.now().time()
            (code, val) = datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib)
            t2=datetime.now().time()
            diff=t2-t1
            logger.debug('RETURN code: ', code)
            logger.debug('Time taken in seconds: ',diff.seconds)

        testlogger.removeHandler(h1)

    # Passing ipaddress of controller and log file name
    t1 = FuncThread(datapaths, "103.0.1.40", "datapaths.log")
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
```

I am getting Attribute error when i run this code when i am trying to call a function in a thread.
This is the error i got.
Please help me with the fix.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "code.py", line 17, in run
    self._target(*self._args)
  File "code.py", line 34, in datapaths
    (code, val) = datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'listDatapaths'
```

Comment: Don't access that attribute on that object. "+15 rep"

Comment: What do you expect `datapaths.listDatapaths` to do?

Comment: `datapaths` is obviously a function—in fact, it's the same function you're in the middle of. You haven't added a `listDatapaths` attribute to it, or to anything else, anywhere in your code. It's obviously not one of the standard built-in attributes you'd expect everything to have. So… what were you expecting this to do, besides raise an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Also, what makes you think this problem has anything to do with threading, logging, or any of the other stuff you're doing? If you don't have think it does, strip it out and post a simpler [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and don't add a bunch of irrelevant tags.

Comment: By the way, why are you writing your own code to call a function 10 times and measure the time? That's what [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is for, and I'm pretty sure the documentation for `time` even directly says "Don't use this for timing code, use `timeit` somewhere.

Comment: I am new to python and these are my initial scripts.Please help me how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this answered:

```
def datapaths(ipaddress, testlogfile):
        # Unecessary code reomved
        (code, val) = datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib)
        # Unecessary code reomved
```

You are trying to access an attribute of a function you've defined, but most likely not set. I think you need to rexamine your code.